# C# ProgressBar Not Filling

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, progress-bar, eventhandler

I am developing an application that uses a progressbar to show the user any development in the program. The program I am writing uses a progressbar to show the user how many packets of data have been sent in the course of execution. I have created an event in the underlying library that triggers once another packet has been transmitted. Here are the event lines I have set up:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ChangedEventHandler PercentageUpdate;

protected internal virtual void OnPercentageChanged(EventArgs e)
{
        if (PercentageUpdate != null) PercentageUpdate(this, e);
}
```

Note that the above code is set up in the underlying library. I have the event triggered in this library like so:

```
//reinitializing is extraneous, as Receive() calls are overwriting
try
{
    fsa.rnd = fsa.TransferSocket.Receive(fsa.File_Buffer, 0, FSArgs.BlockSize, SocketFlags.None);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    fsa.Dispose();
    throw new GeneralNetworkingException("FileSocket receive() failed!", e);
}

fsa.tot += Convert.ToInt64(fsa.rnd);
fsa.TransferPercentage = (fsa.tot/fsa.FileSize) * 100;
fsa.OnPercentageChanged(EventArgs.Empty);   //throw event for form
```

Finally, in the application, I have the event initialized like so:

```
public delegate void UpdatePerc(int index);



f_list[f_list.Count-1].fsa.PercentageUpdate += (sender, e) => filesocket_percentage_updated(sender, e, sel_index);



private void filesocket_percentage_updated(object sender, EventArgs e, int index)
{   
        UpdateP(index);
}



private void UpdateP(int index)
{
    if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new UpdatePerc(UpdateP), new object[] { index });
    }
    else
    {
        if (sel_index == index)     //then redraw progressbar
        {
            if (x_list[index] > 1)
            {
                y_list[index]++;
                if (((int)(y_list[index] % x_list[index])) == 0)
                {
                    z_list[index]++;
                    progressBar1.Increment(1);
                    progressBar1.Update();
                }
            }
            else
            {   
                z_list[index]++;
                progressBar1.Increment(1);
                progressBar1.Update();
                richTextBox1.Text += (z_list[index]+ '\n');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (x_list[index] > 1)
            {
                y_list[index]++;
                if (((int)(y_list[index] % x_list[index])) == 0)
                {
                    z_list[index]++;
                }
            }   
            else
            {
                z_list[index]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to invoke the progressbar to update on a parallel thread. However, nothing happens at all. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c and use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx instead.

Comment: "Nothing happens at all" - breakpoints, mate. What piece of code do you expect to be executed but doesn't?

Comment: progressBar1.Increment(1);

Comment: IS your processing done on, or off, the UI thread?

Comment: I am using breakpoints like Nathan said and have discovered that the even is being fired, and the progressBar1.Value is being updated, but the form is not redrawing. In other words, progressBar1.Update is not doing anything

Comment: processing is done off the UI thread